# Which folders can I move without problems to save space on the main drive?

Tags: path

I am looking for an expert on Blender file paths, directories, asset libraries, cache folders, simulation folders, back folders, etc.

My goal is to set up all the space consuming folders on my secondary drive to keep the space on the main drive free for other important things. Therefore, I want to know and fully understand each and every function and purpose of these folders.

Which folders can I move to a secondary drive without any problems, and which ones need to stay on the main drive?

I just want to set up some of these huge folders etc on my D drive properly without any problems.

Can someone describe to me in layman's terms where, what and why some of these folders are related or separated, etc.?

I have no idea about the hierarchy of all these things.

Is there an easy to understand manual, blog, PDF, website, etc. on this subject? I have already looked at the information in the online Blender software manual and only understand 20% of it.

So any help would be great.

Thank you for your time, patience and support.

Comment: Blender doesn't generally store huge amounts of anything at all, other than the very project you are working in or where you specifically tell it to. Rendered sequences, baked caches and physics, are stored with the project on a folder you specify. Blender is also portable you can even move its installation anywhere you like. As its stands this question is unclear, not sure we can answer it

Answer (score 2):

If you worry so much about space, why even bother installing any Blender thing on C drive to begin with? Install Blender on D.

Then, basically any data you write is either 1) in Blender's Preferences File Paths, 2) aside your .blend file or 3) manually saved by yourself.

### 1) Blender's Preferences File Paths

[image: file paths]

Aside from the Fonts path which you probably want to leave as the one managed by Windows, any other path can be set to your liking.

Be aware: when installing addons, it will still use the default user folder in %AppData%, you must change the target path option in the sidebar while browsing for the addon:

[image: target path]

### 2) aside your .blend file

Some files, like unpacked data or baking caches, are simply written in subfolders aside your .blend file. And when you are working on a new and unsaved file (which you shouldn't for serious work), it defaults to the `temporary files` from your preferences.

So just always save your file on your D drive, and you should be good.

### 3) manually saved by yourself

I reckon this one is self-explanatory, just save file where you want. x)